# Trouble connecting sam local api to secrets manager

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sam, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to set up AWS SAM locally so I don't have to deploy every time I make a code change. But I'm having trouble getting the secrets out of Secrets Manager. I've created a new SAM project using `sam init --runtime java`

I then created a new secret in Secret Manager, and changed the code in the HelloWorldFunction to try to retrieve the secret.

```
package helloworld;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManager;
import com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.model.*;

/**
 * Handler for requests to Lambda function.
 */
public class App implements RequestHandler<Object, Object> {

    public Object handleRequest(final Object input, final Context context) {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.put("X-Custom-Header", "application/json");
        try {
            String secretName = "testsecret";
            String region = "us-west-2";

            // Create a Secrets Manager client
            AWSSecretsManager client  = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard()
                                            .withRegion(region)
                                            .build();

            String secret, decodedBinarySecret;
            GetSecretValueRequest getSecretValueRequest = new GetSecretValueRequest()
                            .withSecretId(secretName);
            GetSecretValueResult getSecretValueResult = null;

            try {
                getSecretValueResult = client.getSecretValue(getSecretValueRequest);
            } catch (DecryptionFailureException e) {
                // Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw e;
            } catch (InternalServiceErrorException e) {
                // An error occurred on the server side.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw e;
            } catch (InvalidParameterException e) {
                // You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw e;
            } catch (InvalidRequestException e) {
                // You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw e;
            } catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());

                StringWriter outError = new StringWriter();
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(outError));
                System.out.println(outError.toString());
                // We can't find the resource that you asked for.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw e;
            }

            // Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
            // Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
            if (getSecretValueResult.getSecretString() != null) {
                secret = getSecretValueResult.getSecretString();
                return new GatewayResponse(secret, headers, 200);
            }
            else {
                decodedBinarySecret = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(getSecretValueResult.getSecretBinary()).array());
                return new GatewayResponse(decodedBinarySecret, headers, 200);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new GatewayResponse("{}", headers, 500);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `sam local start-api` and navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello`,  I get this error:

```
Secrets Manager can’t find the specified secret. (Service: AWSSecretsManager; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: 6881467f-d968-4f4e-ae60-7e3128124cc5)
com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.model.ResourceNotFoundException: Secrets Manager can’t find the specified secret. (Service: AWSSecretsManager; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: 6881467f-d968-4f4e-ae60-7e3128124cc5)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1632)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1304)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1058)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.doInvoke(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:2024)
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.invoke(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:2000)
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.executeGetSecretValue(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:878)
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.getSecretValue(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:853)
    at helloworld.App.handleRequest(App.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoMethodRequestHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:259)
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoHandlerAsStreamHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:178)
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:888)
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:293)
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:64)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:114)
```

But, it's the same code to get the secret that was given in the secrets manager. Is it not possible to connect to real AWS services from sam local? I had a similar issue with DynamoDB, but was able to get it working with by using DynamoDB Local.

Any suggestions on how to either connect to the real secrets manager or to fake it locally somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run DynamoDB Local, it is actually running a mock DDB server in a thread (or as a local process depending on how you start it) within you running test process. Unfortunately, Secrets Manager and other AWS services do not offer an equivalent testing solution.

However, if you are getting back ResourceNotFoundException it seems likely that you were able to successfully connect to Secrets Manager. It may be possible that the connection to secrets manager is using a different account than the one in which you stored the secret. One way you can check which credentials the code is using is to use the [STS get caller identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/securitytoken/AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.html#getCallerIdentity-com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.GetCallerIdentityRequest-) call.

Comment: This was exactly it. I was starting sam local without a profile, so it was using my default profile not my work account. Added `--profile work-profile` and it found the secret. This also fixed the issue I was having connecting to DynamoDB, so now I can connect to our Dev dynamo tables, or have the option to use the local version. Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what I ran into as well, thanks for the post!